# Spring web mvc 3.0 Form data and image upload issue

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am new to spring and JSP. My web application is spring powered, which I run locally in apache tomcat.

In my JSP page I have multiple file-upload inputs and many text input fields.

Every time, when I press any of the upload buttons, a HTTP `POST` request goes to my controller from where on I may save the image to the database.

But, what I want is:

I will upload the images one by one ( preferably by staying in the page) but won't save them in database and then when I press submit to get the rest of the input text fields data, I commit all the data, including image, texts to the database in one try.

I have heard of `scope="session"` for my controller(bean) in the dispatcher-servlet.xml   ... but I am unsure as to if I upload image to my controller and get back to my JSP form, will the bean keep my already uploaded images?

I think it is hard for me to explain, so please let me know if my question is not clear.

It would be nice if anybody can come up with a suggestion that may help to obtain my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you uploading a varying number of images, as in if someone wants to upload only 2 they'll have 2 file fields on the form, or does everyone get 5 fields for example?

To be honest, the whole scheme of incremental upload sounds a bit overcomplicated at this stage. (Unless you have an explicit need to show progress bars on each upload, etc.) What if the user abandons the form after uploading the first image? You'd need a pretty solid mechanism to keep track of the entire visit, keeping it in the session wouldn't help here. Can a user pick up where they left off? If you make the whole thing work with single form submit click first, you can break it out and fine tune the process later. I mention that since you stated you're new to jsp and Spring (what's your experience with web dev otherwise?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to upload file using ajax control rather than submitting form for each upload and store the file references in session scope variable(attribute). there are lot of libraries have ajax based file uploading like extJS, JQuery, GWT, DWR , whatever ajax library you are using in your web application.